# CSS Code doesn't show right color when a <P> tag has a child <H2> tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    /*
    p.second > h2 {
        color: red;
    }
    */
    p > h2 {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

   <p >
      <h2>hello,world</h2>
       <h2>hello,world</h2>
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect to see *hello,world* in red, but it is not.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the close reason states, what are you expecting to see, and what you actually see.

Comment: the style under this { p > h1 } can make the element change its color.

Comment: `p` elements may not contain `h#` elements.

Comment: the son under the father can't change change his color under my style => p > h2

Comment: Change it to `div>h2 { color: red; }` and change `<p>` with `<div>` and your code will work.

Comment: that is because browsers automatically rip the `<h2>` tag out of the enclosing `<p>` tags, because it isn't semantically valid.

Comment: the elements split "block" and "line", is that my dault in the elements?

Comment: @sgsheg You ought to edit this into your question. Once you do that, your question will automatically kick into the review queue for re-opening.

Comment: Looks like only @zzzzBov has any clue around here.

Comment: @sgsheg I fixed the title for you, "What's wrong with my code" is not a good title, and will more often than not get your question closed.  (Mostly because no one will ever search for "What's wrong with my code.")

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that:

```
   <p>
      <h2>hello,world</h2>
      <h2>hello,world</h2>
   </p>
```

Is not valid HTML code (or, at least incredibly *sloppy* HTML code).  A `<p>` tag can only contain inline elements, where-as the `<h2>` tag is a block element.  Basically, once the browser sees the `<h2>` tag it will automatically close the `<p>` tag making the two tags siblings.  You'll need to use another containing element, such as a `<div>`:

```
   <div>
      <h2>hello,world</h2>
      <h2>hello,world</h2>
   </div>
```

Then your style would be:

```
div > h2 {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the `<p> <h2>hello,world</h2>` part of code appears to be _valid_, because the `p` element can be closed implicitely if followed by anything block-level. But its meaning for the HTML parser is rather different from what the author expects from it.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn - Well, yea the parser has to do *something*, as HTML parsers don't just throw up errors like JavaScript does.  Thus, the browser will end the `<p>` tag immediately making the `<h2>` tag a sibling.  Hence, a CSS *child selector* will no longer work.  j08691 alluded to that behavior, below, by suggesting the use of a sibling selector.

Comment: I agree, but specifically in the case of the `p` element it's the specified behavior, not exactly the HTML error.

Answer (score 2):

As mentionted before yo can not put headings inside paragraphs.

This is not just an agreement on web standards or etiquette but an actual impediment, **you can't**

Many browser won't let you do it, they'll tear apart paragraphs and headings.

Therefore any `p h2`or `p > h2` selector wont work, you  try using `p + h2{ color: red;}` (it works for an h2 tag preceded by a p tag) or something like that

[image: Can't wrap headings inside paragraphs]

Answer (score 2):

It's because

```
<p >
      <h2>hello,world</h2>
```

is equivalent to

```
<p >
      </p><h2>hello,world</h2>
```

[because](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags)

> A `p` element's end tag may be omitted if the `p` element is immediately
>   followed by an `address`, `article`, `aside`, `blockquote`, `dir`, `div`, `dl`,
>   `fieldset`, `footer`, `form`, `h1`, **`h2`**, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `header`, `hgroup`, `hr`,
>   `menu`, `nav`, `ol`, `p`, `pre`, `section`, `table`, or `ul`, element, or if there is
>   no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an
>   `a` element.

So the `h2` element can never be a child of the `p` element, unless the page is served with XML Content-type.

Comment: I suppose I should change my answer from *invalid HTML* to *extremely sloppy HTML* - point taken!

Comment: That's not necessary, the whole example is still invalid because of the stray closing `</p>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `h2` into `p` as it's not valid HTML code.
Just replace `p` with a `div` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I advocate this but you can skirt the invalid HTML issue by using the CSS general sibling selector:

```
p ~ h2 {
    color: red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NC5xr/)**

Comment: Probably good to point out that the *reason* this works is because the browser will *close* the `<p>` tag right when it runs into the `<h2>` tag, thus making the two tags siblings..